# substring replacement regex Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to use Notepad++ to substitute some text. I am new to using regex and I am having trouble with this:

- Replace any pattern in the form of `[CHARACTERS]` with `[characters]`, e.g. `[SOMEDATA]` becomes `(somedata)`.

This is what I have, any suggestions?

```
s/^#+$/#
```

It does not work!

Comment: IIRC, Perl has a `y` operator that works like this: `y/ABC/abc/` and translates all occurrences of A to a and so on. Like the unix `tr` command.

Comment: Based on a comments to a now-deleted answer, the OP is using Notepad++, not Perl, despite the two references to the latter and none to the former in his question. I have updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you update Notepad++ to the latest version - they improved the regex engine considerably in recent updates.

If you have a look at the [regex documentation of Notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Regular_Expressions#Substitutions), you'll see that it actually supports control sequences to change the capitalization in the substitution.

I am not quite sure whether you want to match those square brackets as well. If all you want is to turn your match into lower case, then you can use this in the `Replace with:` part:

```
\L$0
```

The `\L` turns everything lower case until an `\E` is encountered, and the `$0` refers to your entire match, so that you can write it back.